# SQL Server Issue When Querying on Specific Records

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I am using the `mssql` Node package to handle various stored procedures in my SQL Server database. I am more familiar with Node than I am with SQL Server, and thus am confused by an error I'm getting. When I run a simple SELECT query like:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [NoteDetailId]
      ,[DocumentType]
  FROM [CVDB].[dbo].[FV_AR]
```

... I have no problem getting data.

However, if I add a WHERE clause, where I'm target a specific value, like so:

```
SELECT [NoteDetailId]
      ,[DocumentType]
  FROM [CVDB].[dbo].[FV_AR]
  WHERE NoteDetailId = 321234
```

... I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00000DELETE' to
>   data type int.

This is the case, even though I can see a row where `NoteDetailId` = `'321234'` in my original query's returned results.

And to clarify, I get this error both when executing code in Node, and when running the same query directly through SQL Server Management Studio.

Also, to clarify, unlike other tables, where I can right click and choose "Design" to see the data types for the various columns, on this particular table, when I click on "Details", I see info such as "CASE when... as", etc.

By the way, I did try wrapping the value in single quotes, as well as in double quotes, but I get exactly the same error.

So what is this error telling me exactly?

Comment: What kind of `NoteDetailId` type?

Comment: WHERE NoteDetailId = `'321234'`

Comment: See what I wrote above. When I click on "Details", I don't see typical data types, I see info like "CASE WHEN... as,", etc. So, I'm not sure.

Comment: Post the DDL for the table. And always post the complete error message - including the severity, etc. And don't use 3 part names without a good, VERY good reason. Why? Because this creates a dependency between the current database of the connection and this "other" database where the needed information is located. For code that is expected to run in the current database of the connection, it is safest to use 2 part (schema.table) names only. This makes supporting multiple environments much easier.

Comment: I suspect that your "table" is really a view and that is the cause of the error.

Comment: you have record(s) it is not INT int's similar **00000DELETE** and sql cannot convert to INT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that what you are calling a "table" is really a view and the error is happening in the view.

The error does not occur in the first 1000 records.  They are fine according to the query plan used for that query.

They do occur for the query plan when you add the restriction -- maybe on that record, maybe on another.

If this is the case, then you should ask a *new* question and show the view definition.

Comment: I think you're right about it being a view now that I look. But to clarify, the record I get the error on is INCLUDED in those first 1000 records I can query successfully.

Comment: @Muirik . . . That doesn't matter, as I explain in the answer.  The error is in the VIEW and related to the query plan.  The bad record happens to be processed as part of the filtered results.  Plus, there could be more than one record that matches and that could be where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, the column `NoteDetailId` is a character data type. You just need to wrap your search term in string delimiters, which, for SQL Server, are single quotes.

```
SELECT [NoteDetailId]
      ,[DocumentType]
  FROM [CVDB].[dbo].[FV_AR]
  WHERE NoteDetailId = '321234'
```

Comment: That's what I thought too. But when I run the query with the value wrapped in single quotes (or double quotes for that matter), I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It means `Nvarchar`, So you should change from `321234` to `'321234'`

```
WHERE NoteDetailId = '321234'
```

**Note:** You can check data type of the column by this way

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'yourColumnName'
```

Comment: As per my comment in the other answer, I actually had tried this already. I still get the same error -- even when the value is wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Could you send us your data value and data type of `NoteDetailId ` ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, when I click on "Details" in SQL Server Management Studio, I don't see typical data types, I see info like ""CASE when... as". So how can I determine the data type?

Comment: You can check data type like `SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'yourColumnName'`

Comment: How about `WHERE CAST(NoteDetailId  nvarchar(100)) = CAST('321234' AS nvarchar(100))`

Comment: When I run the check to get the data type you suggested, I see "DATA_TYPE", but no value?

Answer (score 0):

If quotes aren't working you should be able to force it using a cast

```
WHERE NoteDetailId = CAST('321234' AS nvarchar(20))
```